# css partial border to create 'place holder'

Tags: css, border

Using CSS, how can I create a partial border as per image below

[image]

I can get the complete border with:

```
border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
```

but only want to show maybe 30px at the top and botton of the vertical border with nothing imbetween?

can this be acheived?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a CSS solution, but it's complicated and also requires HTML markup:

```css
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#box > div.corner {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.top {
    top: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.left {
    left: 0px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}

.right {
    right: 0px;
    border-right-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div class="corner top left"></div>
    <div class="corner top right"></div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="corner bottom left"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom right"></div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hRNSN/)

Comment: Legend, works 100%. Now to get my head around it. Thanks a million, really apprecaite your time and teachings. R

Comment: Please can you review http://jsfiddle.net/fgKhR/. this is exactly what I wanted to acheive (except red background of course). Thanks again. have I acheived this in the best possible way as per the advice you gave me or have I taken a good thing and made it worse? thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger It appears you've done fine; the only suggestion I have to offer is that `position: absolute` doesn't seem to be required on `#main`.

Comment: Thanks Daedalus. Really appreciate the input and advice. helped me on my way allot. Thanks again and go well.

Comment: Hi. Stupid question, how can I make the silver border thicker or thinner? http://jsfiddle.net/fgKhR/ thanks again. R

Comment: Firstly, remove `background: white;` from `#content`, then add `border-side-width: 5px(or whatever);` to [your corner style](http://jsfiddle.net/fgKhR/3/).